# Pandas - Get number of elements in already grouped DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get the number of elements in an already grouped DataFrame that was read from a csv-file. The resulting DataFrame can be depicted like so:

| # | Class A | Class B | Class C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2,3,4 | 5 |
| 1 | 2,3 | 1 | 4,5 |
| 2 | 3,5 | 1 | 2,5 |
| 3 | 5 | "1,2,3,4" |  |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

What I want to achieve is the number of elements in the Classes A, B, C for all rows (concrete values not needed, they are in brackets just for visualization):

- 5 occurences of a single element (1, 5, 1, 1, 5)
- 4 occurences of two elements ("2,3", "4,5", "3,5", "2,5")
- 1 occurence of three elements ("2,3,4")
- 1 occurence of four elements ("1,2,3,4")

I tried this by iterating over each row and column, and by splitting the strings to get the amount of elements, like so:

```
for ind in classFrame.index: 
   classes = classFrame['Class A'][ind]
   arr = str(classes).split(",")
   print("len: " + str(len(arr)))

   classes = classFrame['Class B'][ind]
   arr = str(classes).split(",")
   print("len: " + str(len(arr)))

   classes = classFrame['Class C'][ind]
   arr = str(classes).split(",")
   print("len: " + str(len(arr)))
```

However, I don't think this is the correct way, and there may be a more elegant solution to my problem.

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can `stack` all columns, then `split` by comma, calculate number of items with `len` and then `value_counts` of these counts:

```
df.stack().str.split(',').str.len().value_counts()
```

Output:

```
1    5
2    4
4    1
3    1
```

Comment: Nice +1 to make it even easier, you could do a combination of both of our answers with: `(df.stack().str.count(',')+1).value_counts()`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your response. This looks good, but it seems like it doesn't work for cells that only have a single value in them. Do you have an idea what this could cause?

Comment: Can you give an example? In your current question we have 5 cells with a single value (1, 5, 1, 1, 5), and in the output we get '1 5', which is correct, so I'm not sure which case you're referring to

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.count()` with `melt` and `value_counts()`:

```
(df.iloc[:,1:].melt()['value'].str.count(',') + 1).value_counts()

1.0    5
2.0    4
4.0    1
3.0    1
dtype: int64
```

Simplest way -- idea from @perl's answer with `stack`:

```
(df.stack().str.count(',')+1).value_counts()
```